# Python regex not ending with given pattern

Tags: python, regex

Want to write regex in python for which accepts start HTML tag but not self-closing HTML tags.
so the rules will be

```
1.match '<'
2.match any number of space
3.match one alphabet
4.match any number of any character except '>'
5.end **MUST NOT** be a sequence of '/' followed by any no of spaces followed by '>'
```

i.e

Matches case

```
< object src=as/asa __/rn      >  
<      object src=as/asa __  /">
```

Rejected case

```
<a val=ads/arb/     >
<a val=ads/arb   /  >
<a val=ads/arb     />
```

so, in short, I want to match strings not ending with pattern '/ *>'

with a lot of permutation i reached close but not exact, this is what my solution looks like

```
< *[a-z][^>]*[^/]>
```

it fails to reject 1 & 2 reject case
I want to the general approach to tackle the string not ending with given some other pattern. like mine.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following regex:

```
< *[a-z](?:[^\/\n]|\/(?! *>))+>
```

with options:

- `i` - *case insensitive*,
- `g` - *global*, to match all tags.

Details:

- `<` - represents itself.
- `*` - a sequence of spaces (may be empty).
- `[a-z]` - a letter (either case).
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group, with 2 alternatives:

  - `[^\/\n]` - the first alternative: any character different
    from a slash or a newline.
  - `|` - alternative separator
  - `\/(?! *>)` - the second alternative: a slash, not followed
    by a sequence of spaces and ">" (negative lookahead).
- `)+` - the end of the non-capturing group, this group can occur
  many times.
- `>` - represents itself.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/cni3ek/1

If you want to match such cases like `<b>`, replace the last `+` with `*`
(the non-capturing group is allowed to not occur at all).
See https://regex101.com/r/cni3ek/2/